# How to change path to public files on Drupal 8?

Tags: docker, drupal, drupal-8

By default the path to public filesystem is `sites/<site-name>/files` in a multi-site environment or just `sites/default/files` for a single site. How can I change it? I need to keep files on a separate docker volume(s).

Comment: why don't you mount the filesytem directory in another docker container

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the standard folder structure as it is, and use symlinks to actually use a different path (folder, volume, etc) as the real storage.

Here's the folder structure for a Drupal 8 site I have on my local Homestead. **Update the paths according to your own structure.**

```
/home/vagrant/Projects/D/Drupal8/

├── ..
├── private_files
├── public_files
│   ├── ctools
│   ├── field
│   │   └── image
│   └── styles
│       ├── large
│       │   └── public
│       │       └── field
│       │           └── image
│       ├── medium
│       │   └── public
│       │       └── field
│       │           └── image
│       └── thumbnail
│           └── public
│               └── field
│                   └── image
├── vendor
└── web
    ├── includes
    ├── misc
    ├── modules
    ├── profiles
    ├── scripts
    ├── sites
    │   ├── all
    │   └── default
    │       └── files -> (symlink) /home/vagrant/Projects/D/Drupal8/public_files/
    └── themes
```

First **move current public files directory to outside of Drupal root**, or anywhere on your file-system:

```
$ mv web/sites/default/files public_files
```

Create a new `files` directory in its place (Do this only if the next step doesn't work for you):

```
$ mkdir web/sites/default/files
```

**Create the symlink:**

```
$ ln -s /home/vagrant/Projects/D/Drupal8/public_files/ /home/vagrant/Projects/D/Drupal8/web/sites/default/files
```

Two important points to pay attention to:

- Always use full paths instead of relative paths when creating symbolic links.
- Notice the trailing forward-slash usage in source and destination.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Osman, but I really wish to know how to do it w/o any modifications to the filesystem.